# writing two lines in a csv file at the same time

Tags: c#, csv

I have 7 text boxes and I want to write their values to a csv file. Plus, I want to write a label for this information. The final csv file should look like this:

```
label1----label2----label3----label7

value1----value2----value3----value7
```

This is my code:

```
public void CreatingCsvFiles()
        {
            string filePath = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\project2\\" + "filename.csv";
            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                File.Create(filePath).Close();
            }
            string delimiter = ",";
            string[][] output = new string[][]{
                new string[]{this.labels}
            };
            int length = output.GetLength(0);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
                sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, output[index]));
            File.AppendAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
        }
```

as you see, I have used `new string[] {this.labels}`
where this.labels is a **csv formated** string.

everything works fine, but the problem is that I couldn't know who to write the `this.values` to the same csv file.

where `this.values` is a **csv formated** string.

Comment: Eh? surely you just write the labels before you enter the loop... p.s. try using StyleCop

Comment: Not sure why you're using the output array.  Can you just add `this.labels` and `this.values` directly to the StringBuilder one after the other?  Or even write them directly to the file, without the StringBuilder?

Comment: Pau: I tried to make a loop but just the last value printed on the csv file

Comment: Mike: I don't know what is that StringBuilder for, I found that code on an internet page. if you know a better solution, please tell me. thanks

Comment: Was typing a similar comment to Mike.  If this.labels is already a string array (is this true?) then you don't need to create a new output string array.  Just use it directly.  Also, you don't need to do any complicated logic for appending/checking for existing file.  just call `File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Append)`.  This will automatically append if the file exists and create a new file if it doesn't.  don't close the file immediately like in your code.  Use the return value from `File.Open` to write to your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the `File.AppendAllText` add `sb.AppendLine(this.values)`.

Note what your doing is creating the lines of text in the StringBuilder object and then writing them all at once to a file, the other common alternative is to write each line individually.

The StringBuilder approach could be useful if you need to display it as well as write it, but be careful if you start dealing with lots of text, as the StringBuilder object will grow as well.

To write per line then the following should help get you started:

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\csvfile.csv",true))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("HEADER");
                sw.WriteLine("======");
                sw.WriteLine("1,2,3,4");
            }
```

Comment: Note that the `true` parameter to the StreamWriter constructor will cause it to append to an existing file, which will lead to multiple header lines.  Use `false` to replace the entire content of any existing file.

Answer (score 0):

If `this.labels` and `this.values` are **already csv formatted** strings, then you can simply add them to the file:

```
using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("filename.csv"))
{
  w.WriteLine(this.labels);
  w.WriteLine(this.values);
}
```